# Square of Prime Numbers in C

Tags: c

I'm writing code that asks for two positive integers entered from the keyboard.  The first integer N is odd in the range 3-15, and the second will have an initial value I.  N will be the size of the array.  Beginning in the center of the NxN array with the integer I.  If I is prime then print the number I in that position of the square.  Otherwise print three asterisks in that position.  Move to the right one square, and test the integer I+1 for primality.  Print I+1 if it is prime and three asterisks if it is not. Continue going counter clockwise through the square until the square is full of numbers and three asterisks, then print the array.

That's the problem; I have done most of it and am confused as to how to make the array and if any one could take a look at my code to let me know if I have my for loop set up correctly.  Thank you kindly for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    int N, I;

    printf("Enter an odd integer n between 3 and 15: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    printf("Enter an initial value i: ");
    scanf("%d", &I);

    int arr[N][N];
    int k = 1;
    int i = N / 2 + 1;
    int j = N / 2 + 1;

    while(k < N) {
            int s;

            for(s = 0; s < k; s++, i++, I++)
                    arr[i][j] = IsPrime(I) ? I : -1;
            for(s = 0; s < k; s++, j--, k++)
                    arr[i][j] = IsPrime(I) ? : -1;
            k++;
            for(s = 0; s < k; s++, i--, I++)
                    arr[i][j] = IsPrime(I) ? I : -1;
            for(s = 0; s < k; s++, j++, I++)
                    arr[i][j] = IsPrime(I) ? I :-1;
            arr[i][j] = IsPrime(I) ? I : -1;
            k++;

            if(IsPrime(i) == 1) {
                return i;
            } else {
                    printf("***");
            }
    }
            return 0;
}

int IsPrime(int n) {
    int i, count = 0;

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if((n % i) == 0) count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why IsPrime does not return anything?

Comment: its not compiling correctly saying that it wont let me use a variable length array.

Comment: Well, it's not wrong. Have you learned about `malloc` yet?

Comment: yes but i alway get a little confused i thought about using malloc to allocate space for the array which i would use as int* arr; and arr=malloc(sizeof(int*)); to get the space but dont know where to input that within my code.

Comment: Cka91405: I think malloc should be used as this: float*f;int size; scanf("%d", &size);f=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*size); Note three thing here: 1) Malloc is not typesave, you have to cast it in the appropriate pointer type. 2) Make a sizeof() of the type, not the pointer type, as the pointer type will be always of a constant size. (4 Byte on x32 systems, 8 on x64 systems). 3) You are allocation memory for 1 value, i think you forgot to multiply the size with the number of elements. Use the malloc at the same position as you would create a "normal" array with constant size.

Comment: gotcha! but i think my teacher wants an int, but i believe it could would alot better with a float.

Comment: @Michael: wrong. typecast is not needed for malloc in C. Only C++ needs it, see C tag.

Comment: I believe in "C", you cannot declare variables after code. You must declare all variables at top of scope. What you are doing will not work.

Comment: How should i declare the variables?

Comment: After second scanf, use an 'if' statement to verify that user entered appropriate values. Then your other variables will be at the top of the if statement scope.

Comment: i keep getting errors with my array: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘arr’

Comment: Variable length arrays are a C99 feature. Microsoft's C compiler doesn't support C99, so if you're using that, you have to malloc.

Comment: Array indices are 0-based, so you have to start at `i = N/2; j = N/2;`.

Comment: Could someone show me how to do a correct malloc for the array because i cant seem to do it right. Please! & Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so there's a lot wrong here, and plenty to explain. Let's start with the really obvious stuff that prevents this even running, and move on afterwards.
I'm going to use C89, so I'll do declare all my local variables at the start of each method. I'll be using `gcc 4.6.1`, and compiling with `-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic -g -lm`.
We will need the `-lm` shortly - it links to the math library.

### IsPrime()

So, your `IsPrime(int n)` appears to be missing some pieces at the bottom. As such, I can't even say whether it will work or not.

Let's forward declare it by putting `int IsPrime(int n);` at the top of the file just below `#include stdio.h`. While we're at it, let's add some more includes, too:

```
#include <stdlib>
#include <math.h> /* For sqrt() */
```

Now, let's replace the body of the method with something that should work (well, you don't have to, but I will because I can't see the rest of your method):

```
int IsPrime (int n) {
  int i, sqrtN;

  if (n < 2) { return 0; } /* 1, 0, and negatives are nonprime */
  if (n == 2) { return 2; }
  if ((n % 2) == 0) { return 0; } /* Check for even numbers */
  sqrtN = sqrt(n) + 1; /* We don't need to search all the way up to n */
  for (i = 3; i < sqrtN; i += 2) {
    if (n % i == 0) { return 0; } /* Stop, because we found a factor! */
  }
  return n;
}
```

### main() and scanf()

You aren't using arguments to `main()` so let's change it to `int main(void) {`.
When you call `scanf()`, you should check the result - it will return the number of things matched successfully, or `EOF`. You should also check the values it stored, since you require N to have a specific range and I to be positive.

So, let's try using this at the start of `main()`:

```
int N, I;
int s;
int i, j, k;
int **arr; /* More on this later*/

printf("Enter an odd integer n between 3 and 15: ");
s = scanf("%d", &N);
if (s != 1) {
  printf("No proper input provided; program will now exit");
  return 0; /* Or we could use EXIT_SUCCESS, which is defined by stdlib */
} else if (N < 3 || N > 15) {
  /* I have assumed the range of 3 to 15 to be inclusive here */
  printf("I must be positive; program will now exit");
  return 0;
}

printf("Enter an initial value I: ");
s = scanf("%d", &I);
if (s != 1) {
  printf("No proper input provided; program will now exit");
  return 0;
} else if (I <= 0) {
  printf("I must be positive; program will now exit");
  return 0;
}
```

### malloc()

From the comments on your question, you appear to understand that `malloc` allocates memory but not necessarily the correct syntax to get it to do so in this instance.
That's where the `int **arr;` comes in. To allocate your two dimensional array of integers, now that we have a legal value for N, we can do `arr = malloc(N * sizeof arr[0]);`
Now, malloc can fail, so we need to check that `arr != NULL` after that call. And we aren't done yet! That's only one dimension of your array - we've just allocated enough memory for N pointers to one dimensional arrays, pointed to by `arr`.
So we have to loop through and allocate space for those pointers to point to.

So then we do this:

```
for (s = 0; s < N; ++s) {
  arr[s] = malloc(N * sizeof arr[0][0]); /* Enough space for N integers */
  if (NULL == arr[s]) {
    /* We'll just quit instead of handling this gracefully... */
    /* ...because this is only an example */
    printf("Uh oh! Memory allocation failed! Let's run away!\n");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

### free()

Now, because you have allocated memory, you will also need to free it when you are done with it. At the end of your main method, you will need a loop to free each of the one dimensional arrays you allocated space for, and then you will need to free `arr` itself.
Like so:

```
for (s = 0; s < N; ++s) {
  free(arr[s]);      
  /* I am paranoid about setting pointers to NULL */
  arr[s] = NULL;
}

free(arr);
arr = NULL;
/* It can matter if you are going on to do other things instead of exiting. */

return 0;
```

### Logic

So, now for the loop that's actually meant to do the moving around the array.
You are returning `i` from main instead of printing out. I'm pretty sure you intended to print it out instead, right? If you need to print out the whole grid, as a grid, you need to do it in a separate pass after testing all the values with `IsPrime()`. If you just need to print out whether or not the number is prime (well, the number or ***) in a spiralling order starting from the centre, then you don't actually need `arr` at all.

Now, your loop to calculate the numbers is also incorrect (for starters, it runs out of the bounds of the array), but I'm reluctant to solve that for you, because that piece of logic is the point of your homework assignment, so try sorting out everything I've mentioned here first, and then comment if you're still stuck with the logic after that, I guess.

Just by the way, I've avoided changing your variable names, but you might want to consider not mixing `I` and `i` and in general naming things more descriptively.

### Spiral logic

Disclaimer: There may be better approaches, this is just what came to mind. It does work, though.

The way I think about this is that there is an edge between the middle square and the one to the right of it, and another edge between that square and the one above it, and so on. This forms a spiral pattern. If you draw it, you'll also notice that after every second corner, the number of edges before the next corner increases by one (1,1,2,2,3,3). If we keep track of how long the current side is, when it needs to change, what direction we're going, and when to stop (we know there are N*N total squares, so just count the squares you've filled in so far), then this is relatively straightforward:

```
totalSquares = N * N;
currentSquare = 0;
currentSideLength = 1; /* Number of edges/transitions per side before we turn */
currentPositionOnSide = 0; /* How far down a side we are*/
increaseSideLength = 0; /* This keeps track of when to increase currentSideLength */
i = j = N / 2; /* The middle */
direction = 0; /* Which way we're going - using an enum here would be better for clarity */

while (currentSquare < totalSquares) {

arr[i][j] = IsPrime(I);
switch (direction) {
  case 0: /* Right */
    ++j;
    break;
  case 1: /* Up */
    --i;
    break;
  case 2: /* Left */
    --j;
    break;
  case 3: /* Down */
    ++i;
    break;
  default: /* So we can see if something silly goes wrong with the direction! */
    printf("WTH?\n");
    break;
  }

  ++currentSquare, ++I, ++currentPositionOnSide;

  if (currentPositionOnSide == currentSideLength) { /* We're at a corner! */
    ++increaseSideLength; /* Keep track of the number of turns */
    currentPositionOnSide = 0;
    direction = (direction + 1) % 4; /* Wrap around */
    if ((increaseSideLength % 2) == 0) { /* Increase every second corner */
      ++currentSideLength;
      increaseSideLength = 0;
    }
  }
}

/* Ultra crude formatting - you may want to do better than this */
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
      if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
        printf(" *** |");
      } else {
        printf("%4d |", arr[i][j]);
      }
    }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Now, I've checked that this works, but I haven't tested the #@! out of it - that's your responsibility. Also, you'll obviously need to add those variables or reuse some of the ones you already have (I'd really recommend using well named ones, though.)

Also, that code abuses `IsPrime()` by getting it to return n or 0 (0 is not a prime and you said I must be positive, so there's no need to use -1), thus avoiding all your `if IsPrime(I) ? I : -1;` checks.

Comment: Wow your awesome! This is the best help I have ever gotten on this website! Thank you SOO Much!!. I thought about the "logic" part and I get what its suppose to do, but getting it to do it im not sure how to implement the for loop for the different movements of the square.

Comment: OK, so I've update my answer with a couple of minor bug fixes (one of the scanf checks, and IsPrime()), a revised IsPrime that returns 0 or n instead of 0 or 1, for convenience and the logic you need to get your grid, with what I hope is an adequate explanation of how it works.

Comment: Yes very well said ! i wish my teacher could explain as good as this lol. thank you again for your time to help me with this!

Comment: @Cka91405 All good - if that's sufficient then you should probably [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Malloc was a little off i dont know how it became unaccepted i never touched it but the malloc needed to be fixed minor errors but thank you for you help.

Comment: @Cka91405 Er, any idea what was wrong with the malloc (i.e. if there's a mistake in my answer, then I'd like to fix it...)

Comment: @Cka91405 ...it all works fine for me, btw... you didn't compile it as C++ or something (in which case you have to typecast the results of a  `malloc()`), did you?

Comment: i used c to compile it that coud be a reason but also the array was not initialized it shoul have been i=j=N/2;
        arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);
        for (s = 0; s < dN; ++s){
                arr[s] = malloc(N * sizeof (int));

Comment: What I'm saying is that you don't need to do the `(int**) cast on the result of your `malloc()` unless you are compiling it as C++... which I did not. Your `sizeof(int*)` and my `sizeof arr[0]` (etc) are equivalent in this situation, and I did give an example of setting up the the `malloc`ing of the array, so frankly I have no idea what you had problems with - I cut and pasted the necessary parts out of my answer, and it compiled and ran fine, so ... * shrugs * Well, anyway, it's not like it matters that much - you got it to work in the end anyhow.